# libcurl.so.4 no version information available

Tags: ubuntu, curl

`curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)`

This is the error I am getting. This error has not stopped any scripts or apps from running or preforming their tasks, however I do get an email from the system also anytime curl is used.

I have cron jobs that run often. Some every few minutes, others longer and I get emails that will have that error line in it. I have googled the hell out of the string and variations of it. However, I am unable to find anything useful.

What I have done:
Deleted the file `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4`, this makes the error go away and curl still works with no issues. After about 24-48 hours, the file will come back, pop back up in to the folder and I will have to re-delete it. I know this is not the right thing to do, but I am not sure what else to do.

---

Contents of /usr/local/lib/

```
libcurl.a
libgcrypt.la
libgpg-error.la
libruby-static.a
python2.7/
weechat/
libcurl.la
libgcrypt.so
libgpg-error.so
node_modules/
python3.4/
libcurl.so
libgcrypt.so.20
libgpg-error.so.0
pkgconfig/
ruby/
libcurl.so.4.3.0
libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
postsrsd/
site_ruby/
```

---

Installed Packages:

```
$ apt --installed list | grep 'curl'
curl/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 amd64 [installed]
libcurl3/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 amd64 [installed]
libcurl3-gnutls/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 amd64 [installed]
libcurl4-openssl-dev/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 amd64 [installed]
php5-curl/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9 amd64 [installed]
python-pycurl/trusty,now 7.19.3-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-pycurl/trusty,now 7.19.3-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
```

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Anything to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Edit #1 (more info)
The link is aways made at 8:00:01am just after the daily cron job runs.

```
celestia@Canterlot:/usr/local/lib# ls -hal
drwxr-xr-x 10 celestia root  4.0K Jun 11 07:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 celestia root  4.0K Jun 23  2014 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 celestia root  805K May  2 00:16 libcurl.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root   953 May  2 00:16 libcurl.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    16 May  2 00:16 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    16 Jun 11 07:58 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root  424K May  2 00:16 libcurl.so.4.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root   987 May  2 00:20 libgcrypt.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    19 May  2 00:20 libgcrypt.so -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    19 May  2 00:20 libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root  3.5M May  2 00:20 libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root   956 May  2 00:13 libgpg-error.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    22 May  2 00:13 libgpg-error.so -> libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 celestia root    22 May  2 00:13 libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 celestia root  336K May  2 00:13 libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
celestia@Canterlot:/usr/local/lib# stat libcurl.so.4
  File: ‘libcurl.so.4’ -> ‘libcurl.so.4.3.0’
  Size: 16              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 30939991    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/celestia)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-06-11 08:00:01.983201467 -0400
Modify: 2015-06-11 07:58:17.551455525 -0400
Change: 2015-06-11 07:58:17.551455525 -0400
 Birth: -
```

---

```
celestia@Canterlot:/usr/local/lib# apt-file search libcurl.so.4
libcurl3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
libcurl3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

---

```
celestia@Canterlot:/usr/local/lib# ldd libcurl.so.4
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1cdfe000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb2e75f1000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb2e7216000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb2e6ffc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb2e6c37000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb2e6a33000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb2e7ad2000)
```

Comment: Your system is probably compromised.

Comment: That could be, though I have looked into that and have not seen anything running that I have not put in place or anything else weird. I know this is a possibility, but I would think it is more likely to be another app, or curl, or something that would cause this. If I could find what is making the file, it would be start, but I am not able to. I do know the file is remade most mornings at 8am when the cron.daily is run.

Comment: Files don't just appear, except on compromised systems. Try running `checkrootkit`.

Comment: @Wouter Verhelst Ran, nothing found/not infected

Comment: Do you cron automatic security updates? Do you have any custom packages either from a third party repository, or one you compiled yourself? Have you installed any software from source?

Comment: I have the same problem as @Dasoren ... and in my case its a standalone box (not in any network) so I am sure its not compromised. So any fresh ideas?

Comment: @xkcd I found my issue, though I forgot to reply to this with my answer.

Comment: check and past this command output $ldd curl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue turned out to be I had 2 installs of curl on the system. An apt-get install curl and a curl build from source. I ended up removing the curl built from source and everything works fine now. I also tried later removing the apt-get one and rebuilding curl from source again and all was good. But when I reinstalled the curl from apt-get with the source one still installed, the same issue started again. So I removed the apt-get one again.

In short do not have curl on the system twice, issues happen then.

Sorry if this is not well written, I just got up.

Comment: How did you remove one?

Answer (score 5):

I also had such problem in installing CMAKE, I type `cmake`, the output is:

```
cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available     (required by cmake)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

---

Something like yours.I fixed it like this:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 /usr/local/lib/
```

---

Then, I type `cmake -version`, and the result is

```
cmake version 3.2.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Answer (score 0):

before that check this  $ldd curl for any missing linked libraries if found missing then add this line "/usr/local/lib" in /etc/ld.so.conf and run $sudo ldconfig -v the check $ldconfig -p then curl must be able to use missing lib from this directory